# Coldfusion Mappings For Different Locations For Different Applications

Tags: coldfusion

I currently have multiple applications on the same server. The applications are in different folders from each other. 
In the application, we dynamically create a mapping called "custom", which needs to point to the appropriate "custom" folder for each application.

For example, take the following three applications and their paths:

app1 c:\inetpub\app1\custom

app2 c:\inetpub\app2\custom

app3 c:\inetpub\app3\custom

The code I use to do this (called in OnApplicationStart) for one application is:

```
<cffunction name="CreateAppMappings" output="no" returntype="void">
        <cfargument name="absolutePath" required="yes" />

        <cfscript>
            mappingCustom = "/custom";
            serviceFactory = createObject("java","coldfusion.server.ServiceFactory");
            mappings = serviceFactory.runtimeService.getMappings();
            mappings["/custom"] = "#arguments.absolutePath#\wwwroot";           
        </cfscript>

        <cfreturn />
    </cffunction>
```

The problem is, that for one application this works. But for multiple applications it is getting overwritten naturally, because the mapping name is the same.

In order for us to use the same codebase for all apps, this mapping name should be consistent ("custom") for each app. 
So how do we accomplish this?

The only way I could think of is running each application as a seperate instance, using the instance manager in CFAdmin. 
Is that my only option? Or is there something else I may not be aware of?

I am running CF2018.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you not using application specific mappings like referenced here in Ben's article: https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2144-coldfusion-application-specific-mappings-work-with-cfinclude.htm

Comment: Any reason why you are not using `this.mappings` in `application.cfc` for this?

Comment: @RandyJohnson and RRK: Thanks, this looks like it will do the trick. I'm going to test and get back shortly.

Comment: @RandyJohnson: This worked. Thank you. If you'd like to post the answer I'll accept it. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Paolo Broccardo, As per @RRK suggestion you can set is as in your Application.cfc file like below

```
 component output="false" {
        this.name ='Your Apps name';
        this.sessionManagement = true;
        this.sessiontimeout = createTimeSpan(0,1,0,0);
        this.root = getDirectoryFromPath( getCurrentTemplatePath() );
        this.mappings[ '/custom' ] = "#this.root#/folder1" ;
                 .........
                 .........
    }
```

Here the root I've point it as root directory for my application and /custom is for mapping for your custom directory details. You can set it like number things in app.cfc file itself.